# Elements are not being visible even though they are present using nightwatch

Tags: nightwatch.js

I am writing a nightwatch code where i am having trouble finding elements effectively with below given piece of code. The elements i tend find are given as list with class `popover__list-item`. I am not sure whether i am using right way. How can i make the elements visible?

This is for a website that we developed.

'step two' :

```
function (client) {

        client 

        .waitForElementVisible('.user-info', 6000)

        .assert.containsText('.user-info', 'Salvin Thomas')

        .pause(2000)

        .click('.user-info')

        .pause(2000)

        .waitForElementVisible('input[class="popover__list-item"]', 40000)

        .assert.containsText('input[class="popover__list-item"]', 'Log out')
}
```

The expected result is that a popup with logout and account options given as list item popsout and then clicks on logout option from it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use WebDriver protocol API

```
function setSelectorbyDOM() {
    let elements = null;
    client.execute(selector => {
        var arr = [];
        var selectors = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
        for (var i = 0; i < selectors.length; i++) {
            if (selectors[i].clientHeight) {
                arr.push(selectors[i])
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }, ['.user-info', 'css selector'], results => {
        elements = results.value;
    });


    if (!elements.length) throw new Error('Element not found.Please check DOM.');
    return elements;
}

function clickByDOMSelector() {
    let action = null;
    const elements = setSelectorbyDOM();
    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        client.elementIdClick(elements[i].ELEMENT, res => {
            action = res.status;
        });
        if (action !== 0) throw new Error(`Couldn't click to button!`)
    }
    return true;
}

const click = clickByDOMSelector();
```

and so on...

Regards!